# Getting started with Firefox API

Tags: api, firefox

I'm working on an university project where I need to write a program that can access Firefox internal data & events to create stats about user actions. What I would like to have access to is:

- have access to HTTP and HTML data
- be able to listen to HTTP + HTML + Client side scripting events

I've already done a bit a research and found few interesting things (XPCom, Mozilla ActiveX, MozRepl, directly putting Javscript files into Firefox software folder...) but my concern is to start working on this project whilst having missed something and ending up using the wrong tool.

Can you provide me with the name of the tools you know with a brief description of what they do, and what their pros and cons are?

Hopefully with enough replies we'll be able to consolidate all the useful info given into 1 authoritative edit/post/comment on this matter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to do so will be writing your own Firefox extension. [This tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School) is the best one I found to get one started with extension developement.